# How to assign the backbutton in the navigation bar to ouais own custom button?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I'm actually on a project and I have to hide the navigation bar. And instead, I want to use my own custom button. Could you advise please?

Is there something like pullviewcontroller that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `popViewControllerAnimated:` on navigation controller yourself to return to previous view controller.

Answer (score 0):

you could use your `UIViewController` life cycle function to set you navigation bar hide and shown ,

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```